# Leaderboard doesn't add in the screen cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, shared-libraries, game-center, leaderboard

I used the code below to show the Leaderboard but all i got it the console this

```
cocos2d: surface size: 480x320
```

the code:

```
- (void)showLeaderboardForCategory:(NSString *)category
{
    // Only execute if OS supports Game Center & player is logged in
    if (hasGameCenter)
    {    

        // Create leaderboard view w/ default Game Center style
        GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];

        // If view controller was successfully created...
        if (leaderboardController != nil)
        {
            // Leaderboard config
            leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;   // The leaderboard view controller will send messages to this object
            leaderboardController.category = category;  // Set category here
            leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;    // GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday, GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek, GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime

            // Create an additional UIViewController to attach the GKLeaderboardViewController to
            myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

            // Add the temporary UIViewController to the main OpenGL view
            [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myViewController.view];

            // Tell UIViewController to present the leaderboard
            [myViewController presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I called the code like this :

```
    [[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterManager] showLeaderboardForCategory:@"LeaderBoard"];
```

Comment: is `hasGameCenter` global? could it be a false value in the context... therefor not letting you in?

Comment: @Grady Player: Not no false because i used CCLOG(@".."); after it and logged the text to the console

Comment: can [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] ever return nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution I must write :

```
    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

instead of :

```
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myViewController.view];
```